Is FixedInt 32-bits across all 64-bit and 32-bit platforms?
Short Version

FixedInt is platform-independent, fixed to 32-bits, and (on Windows) is equivalent to LongInt
LongInt is platform-dependent, is not fixed to 32-bits

Which is it?
Long Version
From System.FixedInt documentation:

type FixedInt = Integer;
Defines a 32-bit signed integer type.
The size of FixedInt is 32 bits across all 64-bit and 32-bit platforms. The range for the FixedInt type is from -2147483648 through 2147483647.

On Windows platforms (32-bit and 64-bit Windows), FixedInt is equivalent to the LongInt type.


Ok, so FixedInt is "equivalent" to LongInt (on Windows; which I am on). Which is confirmed in the source:
System.pas
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  FixedInt  = LongInt;
  FixedUInt = LongWord;
{$ENDIF}

LongInt
We check the System.LongInt documentation:

type Longint = { built-in type };
Platform-dependent signed integer type.
LongInt represents a subset of the natural numbers. LongInt size and range depend on the target platform:

On 32-bit platforms and 64-bit Windows platforms, LongInt is an 4-byte signed integer with the range [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]. (-2-31 through 232-1).

Note: 32-bit platforms include 32-bit Windows and Android.


On 64-bit POSIX platforms (Android, iOS, Linux, and macOS), LongInt is an 8-byte signed integer with the range [-9223372036854775808 .. 9223372036854775807] (-263 through 263-1).
Note: If you want to use a 4-byte signed integer type, use Integer or FixedInt.



So summarize

FixedInt is platform independent 32-bit, and is equivalent to LongInt
LongInt is not platform independent

So which is it?
Is FixedInt really both 32-bit and 64-bit depending on 32-bit or 64-bit platform? Or is this simply a documentation bug?

If we are talking Windows only, then FixedInt is always Integer, that is, always 32 bit. And this is also the same thing as LongInt. I actually don't see any contradiction at all in the docs. Could you please explain exactly where you see the contradiction?

"not fixed to FixedInt" doesn't mean it can't be identical on some platforms, it just means the specification doesn't require it to be identical on every platform. There's no contradiction here.

@AndreasRejbrand You say, "FixedInt is always Integer". The documentation, and the RTL source, says its equavlent to LongInt. Contradiction. Which is it? Integer like you say, or LongInt which the documentation and the source code say?

LongInt on windows is the same as Integer, is 32 bit, so on windows fixedint=longint=integer=32bit, on other platforms, fixedint=integer=32bit

Yes, it is true that x = y and x = z may seem like a contradiction, before you realise that y = z. With the restriction to Windows, all these are the same, as the docs correctly say.

@AndreasRejbrand Ohh, i see what you're saying. FixedInt is 32-bit on all platforms when we limit our platforms to just Windows.

Please notice the important part "On 32-bit platforms and 64-bit Windows platforms, LongInt is an 4-byte signed integer". So while LongInt depends on platform, it is actually platform-independent if you restrict the set of platforms to Windows platforms. It's like "number of legs" is not independent of species within Animalia (humans 2, dogs 4, ants 6, spiders 8, etc.). But if you restrict your attention to a particular subset of Animalia, canines (say), it does become species-independent, because all canine species have 4 legs.

Yes, I do suppose all platform-dependant types (i.e. NativeInt, NativeUInt, LongInt, LongWord) are platform-independant when we limit ourselves to one platform. It's just quite a gotcha when you expect a "platform independant" type to be dependant on the platform.

@IanBoyd The "Delphi platform-independant Integer types" table you quote is not what is actually shown on the page you linked to. In any case, Fixed(U)Int is 32bit on all platforms (hence their names), as are Integer/Cardinal and (U)Int32. LongInt is 32bit (Windows) or 64bit (Posix), as are Native(U)Int and LongWord.

Indeed, the docs clearly state "The size of FixedInt is 32 bits across all 64-bit and 32-bit platforms." so your ASCII-art table is wrong.

The addition of these two types is one of the most pointless and confusing things they have done in the past decade. They serve no purpose than to confuse people. 32bit signed and unsigned ordinal types already exist that are the same on all platforms.

TL;DR
FixedInt and Integer are both platform-independent, 32-bit integer types.
The Problem With The Documentation
Unnecessary Distinction Requires Qualification
The documentation for System.FixedInt introduces an unnecessary distinction between equivalent types on different platforms:


On Windows platforms (32-bit and 64-bit Windows), FixedInt is equivalent to the LongInt type.
On OSX32, 32-bit iOS, 64-bit iOS, and Android platforms, FixedInt is equivalent to the Integer type.


By stating the equivalence on Windows in terms of LongInt (a platform dependent type), the fact that this equivalence applies only on Windows means that if you click-thru to the documentation for the LongInt type, you have to remember that to understand how it is equivalent to FixedInt in the context of that platform.
This is not helped by the fact that the FixedInt documentation establishes a context of "Windows platforms" and helpfully clarifies with "32-bit and 64-bit Windows". If you then read the LongInt documentation, a similar phrase is encountered: "32-bit platforms and 64-bit Windows platforms". But this now means ALL 32-bit platforms (including but not limited to 32-bit Windows) AND in addition 64-bit Windows.
i.e. FixedInt is always 32-bit, and on Windows, LongInt is also 32-bit.
Meanwhile, the FixedInt equivalence for other platforms is stated as Integer, a platform independent type.
It would have been equally valid to say, "FixedInt is equivalent to Integer on all platforms", and leave it at that.
In other words, the documentation is not wrong but less clear than it might be, requiring careful reading. :)
